# Cross Site Scripting issue

Tags: jsp, jstl, xss

To solve the cross site scripting issue, I used the following code to escape special characters:

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>
    <c:set var="linkParam" value="${fn:escapeXml(linkParam)}" />
```

And when run the code, I can see special character is escaped in page source:

```
    <a href='/result.jsp?name=O&#39;Neil'>O'Neil</a>
```

But when clicked the link, browser still show the "/result.jsp?name=O'Neil' in address bar, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is by design.
The browser will decode the attribute value when navigating to the link.

However, you still need to **URL**-parameter-encode the link value in case it has characters like `%` or `&`.

Comment: Thank you SLaks. But if browser always do the decode, how can I prevent cross site scripting?"

Comment: @June: The browser decodes the **value** when reading the attribute.  It does not interfere with the HTML parsing; if you try `"><script>`, it will be escaped as an attribute with that value.

Comment: "/result.jsp?name=O'Neil" shows cross site scripting error when access off our network, that's why I encode the parameter with fn:escapeXml. Does it mean that I should try other approach to escape the url?

Comment: @June: It sounds like you have an over-zealous XSS filter.

Comment: How to fix your XSS? No idea.